# c# How do I stop "CheckBox CheckedChanged" from firing prior to form loading?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, event-handling, datetimepicker

I am building a system for managing contacts and I need to timestamp the date that a checkbox is ticked on a form into a datepicker. I have tried using the CheckBox_CheckedChanged but the problem with this is it fires when the program first loads and also when the next record is loaded, this means every record which is viewed or first loaded ends up being timestamped regardless of whether the tickbox is actually ticked.

How do I prevent this from happening?

```
private void send_TraceCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.last_UpdatedDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the checked changed method gets trigger when the values is initially set.

I assume you only want to save the update time if the value actually changes?
If that is the case you could check if the value gets changed and only then update the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, as a newbie to this how would I go about checking for a value change?

Comment: save the value of the checkbox in a seperate variable and when the checked change function is triggered, check if the value of the checkbox is different than the last value you saved. if its the same you can ignore it